# My picture doesnt show up? (newbie Q)

Tags: html, image

File structure:

[image: file structure]

Code :

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Metnik EL Logo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src ="/images/metnikElHeaderLogo.jpg" alt="metnikHeadLogo" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Really dont understand what im doing wrong..
Btw have tried with ../images and tried with setting height and width aswell.

Comment: metnikHeadLogo?! Please read [Use of ALT texts in IMGs](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html)

Comment: Thanks for that, however, webpage will be completely useless if not this picture is displayed. And i just attached the alt= to make sure it wasn't the outcome-deciding factor.
But still, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From index.jsp, the path to your image should be

```
<img src ="images/metnikElHeaderLogo.jpg" alt="metnikHeadLogo" />
```

From other files within the "pages" folder, then you will need:

```
<img src ="../images/metnikElHeaderLogo.jpg" alt="metnikHeadLogo" />
```

Comment: top one worked, even though its the header.jsp that did the trick, can you tell me why it wasn't ../ ?

Answer (score 0):

You use absolute path to image, and in your case you must use relative path ([further reading](http://www.uvsc.edu/disted/decourses/dgm/2120/IN/steinja/lessons/06/06_04.html))

in your case you must use this notation

```
<img src ="./images/metnikElHeaderLogo.jpg" alt="metnikHeadLogo" />
```

where is:

**"./"** — relative path begining string, meaning that path located in the same folder, as an file, where string was written

**"images/"** subfolder in the same folder